# Change id of linked object google doc

Tags: object, google-sheets, documentation

I have a google doc with more than 50 linked objects synchronized with a google sheet A. I have copied the google sheet A to a B version. Now, I would like to develop a script that change the ID of all linked objects from A to B  in google doc.

[Edit] Please find an example here :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18hOUCkqF3GtRq_vVjKbNap39G-K0VX7q

"Report" contains two associated objects linked to "Data" sheet. I have duplicated "Data" to "Copie de Data". Now, I would like all linked objects from "Report" to point to "Copy de Data".

Is it possible ? Is there an app script that change the id source of objects ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the linked objects mentioned are referenced in the actual contents of a Google Sheets file (value of a cell for example).

You can use several methods from [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) or Apps Script native classes like [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) for example, to modify contents on a file according to your script logic.

I'd recommend taking a look at the specific methods [spreadsheets.values.batchGetByDataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGetByDataFilter) from Sheets API or [Sheet.createTextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext) from Apps Script to find the location of the value you'd like to be modified, then using either [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) from Sheets API or on Apps Script using the TextFinder object (mentioned above) to replace with the new value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I don't really want to change the values of the sheet. I really need all linked objects to point at a new sheet. Please find an example in the original post.